# Scrapy Storage function

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a small scrapy project that I'm trying to work on and whilst I've gotten scrapy to work, I'm a bit stumped by the storage options.

So I have ubuntu 20 headless, the latest python installed and installed scrapy everything is running nicely.

My script is thus:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "github"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://osint.digitalside.it/Threat-Intel/lists/latesturls.txt',
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidonzo/Threat-Intel/master/lists/latesthashes.txt',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'github-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

I execute the script like this :

```
sudo scrapy crawl github -o results.json
```

and get this result:

```
barsa@ubuntu20~/scrape/scrape/spiders$ sudo scrapy crawl github -o results.json
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.0 started (bot: scrape)
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) - [GCC 9.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-5.4.0-48-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'scrape',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrape.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrape.spiders']}
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: xxxxx
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://osint.digitalside.it/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidonzo/Threat-Intel/master/lists/latesthashes.txt> (referer: None)
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [github] DEBUG: Saved file github-lists.html
2020-10-14 09:36:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://osint.digitalside.it/Threat-Intel/lists/latesturls.txt> (referer: None)
2020-10-14 09:36:45 [github] DEBUG: Saved file github-lists.html
2020-10-14 09:36:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-10-14 09:36:45 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 995,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1444016,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/400': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.727767,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 9, 36, 45, 27397),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 52645888,
 'memusage/startup': 52645888,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/400': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 9, 36, 44, 299630)}
2020-10-14 09:36:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Now I check the json file and it's empty, but the github-lists.html contains both lists with no separator between them, so it looks like one large long list.

What I don't understand is how I can do one of the following:

1. Split the lists into their own separate files (github-list1.html and github-list2.html)
2. add a separator into the github-list.html, so I can run some logic to extract this into two separate CSV files perhaps

I can't find any examples on the scrapy site that shows how the file storage works

```
 filename = f'github-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

What would be the best way to tackle this? Because as I see it, this function above only seems to be dealing with a single file instance... so I was thinking maybe I need to use the pipelines function?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
scrapy crawl github -o results.json
```

The parameter `-o` is telling scrapy to use the `FEED_EXPORT` ([docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exports)), however your spider never yields any items to the engine so nothing is exported, that's why your json is empty.

Just so you can see it working, you can add the following line at the bottom of your `parse` method, execute the spider (using `-o results.json`) again and you will see the urls in the json.

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    yield {'url': response.url} # Add this
```

---

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'https://osint.digitalside.it/Threat-Intel/lists/latesturls.txt',
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidonzo/Threat-Intel/master/lists/latesthashes.txt',
    ]
    ...

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = f'github-{page}.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

Here your code splits the response url into a list and get the "last but one" element on the list to name the file. If you check, for both URLs, the element will be "lists" (*coincidence*) therefore both times the `parse` method is called it will reference the same file `github-lists.html` (Where lists came from the `page` variable).

You can use here any logic you want to name your files.

---

I suggest you keep reading the Scrapy tutorial, you will understand better how you can leverage the framework to extract and store the data.

Specially those three sections:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data-in-our-spider

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#storing-the-scraped-data